# Tomcat 7.0.42 crashes with grails app

Tags: java, grails, web-applications, tomcat7

i have an exception in tomcat 7.0.42. The only thing i am doing is deploying a grails app in the webapps directory. I have changed nothing in the config... and tomcat was working fine until recently.

i really havent find what was making trouble between my war and tomcat.

I searched in the archive, and found that some jars could probably conflict. i've found that jetty.jar and servlet.jar which are present in the WEB-INF could a source of conflict, but didnt find any of them in my WEB-INF directory...

this is my stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

does anybody here have an idea of the cause of this problem when its not due to conflicting jars?

Comment: You JSP file may have an invalid EL expression. Check syntax!

Comment: Do a dependency report on your grails app, I suspect you might have something that's pulling in the `tomcat` Grails plugin in compile scope rather than build scope, which would put tomcat JARs in your WEB-INF/lib when you build a war.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? For others in the same situation please accept an answer or provide your own answer.

Comment: Sorry i let this post without answer. I found a solution using the embarqued tomcat in netbeans. I tried to analyze the code using the tools you gave to me but foung nothing, i removed some jars too but it did not change anything!

Answer (score 0):

Search for the Class `org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl` in your classpath. I am quite sure you will find more then one entry. Also this Class might be located in the tomcat libs dir. Check there as well if otherwise not found.

Here is a list of some tools that can assist you analyzing the classpath. Some of them need maven.

http://www.jboss.org/tattletale

http://mojo.codehaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banDuplicateClasses.html

https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin

hope this helps to track down your problem.

**Another option during runtime is to do following:**

Start tomcat with the jvm option `-verbose:class`. This will print out all the classes that are loaded and the jars they are coming from. Grep for `ELContextImpl` to find out the jar. Remove the jar and see if it is working again.

Comment: Thanks Vadimo for the help.

i've search in the jars in apache/lib but didnot find more than one entry. What i've done is :
find path/to/libs -name '*.jar' -exec grep -Hls ClassName {} \;